# how to read the following css class

Tags: css

I have the following `CSS` class :

```
 #menuAccordion h2 a,.dir-rtl #menuAccordion .viewList{
     padding-right:2.5%;
     padding-left:0
 }
```

WOuld it be correct to interpret this as for all HTML elements that use css class `menuAccordian`, if there is an `<H2>` or `<A>` tag inside this element, it will apply the padding that's defined inside the `{}`?
what do the `.dir-rtl` and `.viewList` refer to?

Also, if I had the following code all on one line in my css:

```
 #secNav #showHideMenu a.fixed{
     position:fixed;
     top:0
 }

 .HomePage #content{
     min-height:300px
 } 

 #content{
     background-color:#FFF;
     min-height:600px;
     position:relative;
     z-index:0
 }
```

Can I assume that each time I see a `#`, that it's the start of a new class, and can I also assume that these classes are NOT related to each other?
I'm just trying to understand why the author would have put all this on one line.  It's not readable.  But maybe it's because they're related.

Thanks.

Comment: Class names are prefixed with a `.` (eg. `.className`), ids are prefixed with a `#` (eg. `#idName`).

Comment: # is an ID, rather than a class. It will apply to a single, unique, element.

Comment: I suggest 1) to never put all in one line, and 2) to put the `;` to the last element too, because when you will come back to add some attribute to that style declaration, you will forget to add `;` to the former-last element

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, terminology. The part before a set of curly braces is called a **selector**. There can be multiple selectors separated by commas. In a selector, you can use `#name` to match elements by their `id` attribute and `.name` to match them by their `class` attribute.

---

CSS selectors match the *last* item listed, generally speaking.

```
#menuAccordion h2 a
```

This matches `<a>` elements inside `<h2>` elements inside an element with `id="menuAccordion"`.

```
.dir-rtl #menuAccordion .viewList
```

This matches an element with `class="viewList"` inside an element with `id="menuAccordion"` inside an element with `class="dir-rtl"`.

The meaning of the `viewList` and `dir-rtl` classes is up to the page author. They have no inherent meaning.

---

Putting everything on one line doesn't change the meaning of the CSS. It's probably just a space-saving tactic at the expense of readability.

Comment: Sorry, I just updated my question before I saw this.  Would you mind answering the part B?  Thanks by the way for the clear answer!

Comment: Note that the elements don't have to be direct descendants.  The first selector will match both of these anchors:  `<div id="menuAccordion"><h1><a href="#">Title</a></h1></div>` *and* `<div id="menuAccordion"><h1><span><a href="#">Title</a></span></h1></div>`

Comment: To add to this and clarify a little, the comma in the selector seperates multiple selectors, so you apply the css within the brackets to all elements that match any of the preceeding selectors.